# Visual C# Program 'xyz' does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, visual-c#-express-2010

I apologize if this question has already been asked. Also, please bear with me as I am new to C# and just beginning to learn it. I am trying to write a simple program (hello world) to learn, but when I compile the program I get an error. Below is the screen shot after I try to build the solution. I would appreciate any help on this. [image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Main`, not `main`. C# is case-sensitive.

Comment: Thank you. I usually write T-SQL programs and that is not case sensitive. Hence the simple error. I will accept this as an answer in a few minutes as the site is not allowing me to do so right now.